# Problems in Text to Image Replacement

Tags: php, html, string, replace

I am trying to make a text replacer but since there are letters repeated i keep getting things i dont want. Does anyone know how i can do this?

**Input**

```
function image($img) { 
      $img = ereg_replace("a","<img src=r/a.png>", $img); 
      $img = ereg_replace("b","<img src=r/b.png>", $img); 
      $img = ereg_replace("c","<img src=r/c.png>", $img); 
      return $img; 
} 

 $img = "abc"; 
 echo image($img);
```

**Output**

```
<img sr<img src=r/c.png>=r/a.png><img sr<img src=r/c.png>=r/b.png><img src=r/c.png>
```

**Output I Want**

```
<img src=r/a.png><img src=r/b.png><img src=r/c.png>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, may be insufficient but it will satisfy your requirement:

```
function image($img) {
      $data=""; 

      for( $i = 0; $i <= strlen($img); $i++ ) {
        $char =substr( $img, $i, 1 );
        switch($char)
        {
            case 'a':
                 $data .="<img src=r/a.png>";
                 break;
            case 'b':
                 $data .="<img src=r/b.png>";
                 break;
            case 'c':
                 $data .="<img src=r/c.png>";
                 break;
            default:
            break;
        }
      }
      return $data; 
} 

 $img = "abc"; 
 echo image($img);
```

Comment: Thanks i found it helpful!

Answer (score 0):

Problem with `"c"` your `"a"` and `"b"` replacing correctly but when it reach `"c"` there are many `"c"` cause `"src"` also added so it replaces all `"c"`

try with single statement

```
function image($img) { 
      $img = ereg_replace("abc","<img src=r/a.png><img src=r/b.png><img src=r/c.png>", $img); 
      return $img; 
} 

 $img = "abc"; 
 echo image($img);
```

Also [ereg_replace()](http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.ereg-replace.php) has been deprecated

Comment: I want to stay with multiple statement because i will add the whole alphabet later to create something like a logo maker.

Comment: try to use str_replace() or preg_replace()

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I tried:-

```
function image($img) { 
        for($i=0;$i < strlen($img);$i++){
            $letterarray[]=$img[$i];
        } 
        $a=0;
        foreach ( $letterarray as &$value) { // reference
           $value= str_replace($value, "<img src=r/$value.png>", $value);
            $a++;
            $ab[] = $value;
        }
      return implode("",$ab);
} 

 $img = "abc"; 
 echo image($img);
```

Here in the function `image()`, you don't need to specify the alphabets contained in `$img`